# c netbeans file was built for unsupported file format

Tags: c, macos, netbeans

Am trying to build a c program in netbeans on mac osx 10.7.5 and am getting the following error. I am not sure what is going on. I am trying to learn c.

```
"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:73: warning: overriding commands for target `build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/UnsortedList.o'
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:68: warning: ignoring old commands for target `build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/UnsortedList.o'
"/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/cs350_lab6_linkedlist
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:73: warning: overriding commands for target `build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/UnsortedList.o'
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:68: warning: ignoring old commands for target `build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/UnsortedList.o'
mkdir -p dist/Debug/GNU-MacOSX
gcc     -o dist/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/cs350_lab6_linkedlist build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/UnsortedList.o build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/UnsortedList.o build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/main.o 
ld: warning: ignoring file build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/UnsortedList.o, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64)
ld: warning: ignoring file build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/UnsortedList.o, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64)
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_CreateList", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_InsertItem", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_DeleteItem", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_PrintList", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [dist/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/cs350_lab6_linkedlist] Error 1
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 71ms)
```

If i put all the methods definitions in the main file instead of writing separately in implementation file, then it's building fine and showing no error.

Comment: (By the way, the error message is very concise and clear.)

Comment: SO/Google links i came across were specifically talking about c++.

Comment: @H2CO3 The error may not be sufficiently clear to a student.